# Android Studio print DB contents

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I have a database with student ID's and scores that i'm trying to print out in a fragment in an android app but I can't seem to figure out how to go about doing that.

My initial thought was to use a bunch of textviews that are connected to cells in the database, but if the size of the database changes then not all of it would print out. Is there a dynamic way of going about creating textviews based on the size of the database?

Comment: Why don't you use RecyclerView/ListView ?

Comment: You can do a simple test printing the DB content in a log with Log class.

Answer (score 0):

Use recyclerview for this. It provides scrolling also if the amount information exceeds size of the screen. Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k) for learning how to implement it.